# Bind function on newly created element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to create new html element with `v-on` call. However after I call function pasted below the v-on is not rendered so nothing happens after click. Is there anyway I can force vue to re-render this element?

```
createFromTemplate: function() {
    var el = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));

    el.innerHTML = '<a href="#" v-on="click: close()"></a>;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing that you do to populate the element:

```
el.innerHTML = '<a href="#" v-on="click: close()"></a>;
```

can be done to assign a function:

```
el.onclick = function() {
    //do stuff
}
```